# Reading a variable stored in a URL

Tags: javascript, html

i wanted to use a variable that i manualy inserted in my url

for example the url test.coaching.com?c=1

then i wanted to check if the var c had any value attached to it, if it had i would show a label and a textbox if it hadnt i would hide it

Here is my code so far:

```
function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
        }

         function start()
         {
            var first = getUrlVars()["c"];

            if ( first == "")
            {
                document.getElementById("labeler").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("emailcoacher").style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("labeler").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("emailcoacher").style.display = "block";
            }

         }
```

The problem is i cant get it to read the variable, is there someting im doing wrong?

Comment: URL parsing is actually not a trivial task, yes you could get something working with regex etc, but using a battle tested library would make more sense, .. eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse

Comment: Refer to this working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Keith Modern browsers actually make this very easy. `new URL('https://test.coaching.com?c=1').searchParams.get('c');` You can check browser compatibility [here.](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams)

Comment: I completely vouch with @Keith here, by creating your own URL Parser, you are open to more than a dozen security and performance issues. Using a supported library at the least guarantees that these flaws were tested and are safe. The link added has `2 dependencies` so be aware of that.

Comment: @BenFortune  Yes, modern browsers make this a lot easier,.   Personally I try and find solutions that work Client & Server side.   In a way URL is also a library function, and my point about parsing not been trivial of course still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It's URL param not a hash, so updated answer below.

You could use the `URL` object.

```
var url_string = window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);
```

answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

---

*Ignore:*
If you want to get the hash from an url, try to use.

```
window.location.hash
```

and then just deconstruct the hash to your needs.

Comment: It's not a hash. It's a query parameter.

Comment: well, true in the context. thanks @BenFortune will update answer

Answer (score 0):

I am basically repeating what [**`Ben Fortune`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615209/ben-fortune) mentioned.

---

Most browsers support [`URL Interface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) which allows you to cleanly parse parameters out of the URL using `.searchParams.get(args)`

---

```js
let url = new URL('https://test.website.com?c=1&b=2');

let b = url.searchParams.get('b');
let c = url.searchParams.get('c');

console.log(`B: ${b}\nC: ${c}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function :

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```